# Comparing two LPCSTR with ==

Tags: c++, string, mfc, lpcstr

I found out an implementation that compares two LPCSTR doing the following:

```
void check(LPCSTR lpText)
{
    if(lpText == input)
    {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

The problem is that it works. I replaced it with...

```
if(lstrcmpi(lpText, input) == 0)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

and though I feel safer now.

I just wanted to know if the other implementation was just checking the addresses or the sizes, how did it work?

I checked the memory address of one LPCSTR and it is 0x0633522c and the other is 0x028a91a4.

This shakes my entire foundation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `input` in your first example is a `CString` instance, and there is an overload of `operator==` taking a raw C-style string pointer and a `CString` (`const CString&`), that does the right thing of string comparison.

In fact, in `cstringt.h` ATL header file, you can find:

> ```
> friend bool operator==(
>     _In_z_ PCXSTR psz1,
>     _In_ const CStringT& str2) throw()
> {
>     return( str2.Compare( psz1 ) == 0 );
> }
> ```

Comment: This! input is an element of a CStringArray. Thank you very much. I shall mark this in a few minutes when I can.